# метод read возвращает пустую строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Код должен перебирать файлы из ключей словаря и если файл непустой, то содержимое файла должно становится значением ключа, но вместо содержимого почему-то устанавливается пустая строка.

Код:

```
files = {"logs_2.txt":None, "logs_3.txt":None, "logs_4.txt":None}
for file in files:
    f = open(file, "r")
    if len(f.read()):
        files[file] = f.read()
    f.close()
print(files)
```

Файл logs_4.txt:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Stdout после print(files):

```
{'logs_2.txt': None, 'logs_3.txt': None, 'logs_4.txt': ''}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда вы делаете `read`, то после чтения из файла питон запоминает, на каком месте файла он остановился, и следующий `read` будет с этого же места.

Но это имеет хоть какой-то смысл, только когда вы читаете файл частично.

Если же вы используете `read()` без указания, сколько именно надо читать, то файл вычитывается полностью, и для следующего `read` ничего не остаётся.

В `len(f.read())` уже целиком вычитали файл, и следующий `read` ничего нового уже не прочитает.

Надо так:

```
files = {"logs_2.txt":None, "logs_3.txt":None, "logs_4.txt":None}
for file in files:
    f = open(file, "r")
    data = f.read()          # Делаем read только один раз
    if len(data):            # А потом используем сохранённое значение
        files[file] = data   # сколько угодно раз
    f.close()
print(files)
```

Comment: Типовая в общем-то ошибка )

Comment: кстати можно записать просто `if data`

Comment: Спасибо, забыл, что курсор сохраняет своё место